# C++ shapes library exception handling

Tags: c++, c++11

I want to write some kind of "Shapes library" program.

Not to write a lot of code, let's say we have just an abstract base class Shape and some derived classes, for example, Line, Rectangle and Circle (I think it's not so important to describe them).

Considering that the main function will be something like this:

```
int main() {

    Shape *rect = new Rectangle(Pixel(25, 10), Pixel(33, 15));
    Shape *line = new Line(Pixel(1, 12), Pixel(23, 12));
    Shape *circle = new Circle(Pixel(37, 12), 2);
    refresh_shapes(); // just draw every created shape
    cin.get();

    rect->rotate_left();
    refresh_shapes();
    cin.get();

    rect->move(45, 12);
    refresh_shapes();
    cin.get();

    line->up(rect); // place the line right above the rect
    refresh_shapes();
    cin.get();

    circle->down();
    refresh_shapes();
    cin.get();

    return 0;
}
```

how should I handle exceptions that might be thrown in constructors or maybe after moving (if shape is out of screen bounds)?

For example, if I wrap whole code in one try-catch block, I'll see on the screen everything that happened before throwing an exception. But I want to "save" as much as possible. Is there a better solution than wrapping almost every line in try-catch block?

Sorry for bothering, just want to understand how it works.

Comment: Don't throw exceptions for trivial failures that are not exceptional but that are expected to occur as a regular feature of using the objects.

Answer (score 1):

Don't throw exceptions for trivial failures that are not exceptional but that are expected to occur as a regular feature of using the objects.

Where to draw the line is a matter of judgment. Some of us are still learning it!

When creating an object if you run out of memory then an exception is rightly raised because all future allocations are also likely to fail. However when an object is simply not located in the screen area then you could simply fail to display it.

A balance needs to be drawn between throwing exceptions for the truly exceptional errors (that are locally non-recoverable) and regular failures that are part of the expected behavior and that are immediately recoverable from.

That way you don't end up wrapping every call with a `try/catch` but also we don't need to check for every possible error every time we call a function.

Comment: Thanks for reply! What about something like std::invalid_argument exception if something wrong was passed to constructor?

Comment: @ArtemAliev Constructors **must** put the object into a valid state and, as such, I would say that bad arguments should throw an exception. After all bad argument values is an indication that your program is in a bad state (how did those values get bad?) So bad arguments should be truly exceptional and not (locally) recoverable from. That said, you can have more than one constructor and I think you should aim to have a default constructor that causes no exceptions (and is also marked `noexcept`). Then you can construct your object and then give it the value it needs through its interface.